# Isn't the use of $this redundant when caling a member function within a class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, member-functions

My question is about the design purpose of `$this`. Why use `$this` within a class to call a member function, isn't the class aware of its own functions, and aren't the functions aware of each other therein?

It's like a sister calling her brother - Hey, my brother Mark, the son of Mary who is also my mother, come over here;

Did I make myself clear? I couldn't find a similar question, and I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: I believe some languages permit the 'self instance' reference to be omitted, but PHP does not. If you remove the `$this->` it will try to find a global function of that name instead.

Comment: $this is to use a private of protected function or variable, using $this upon a private thing is to call it from within the class itself or $this on protected can be done upon childs or parents

Comment: Suppose you wanted a class function `date_format`, how would it disambiguate between that and the PHP function, etc?

Comment: @halfer, your comment is the most helpful so far.

Comment: Im going to delete this questoin, because few seem to understand it.

Comment: *Im going to delete this questoin* You ask a question here and I take my time to answer it and explain to you how php handles this and I answer your comments and so on...

Comment: @Rizier123: now that you have votes on your answer, it cannot be deleted by the OP as far as I know. Agreed, it isn't _nice_ if a question one has worked on gets deleted, after a big effort is made. /cc Marina.

Comment: @Rizier123 I wouldve appreciate your answer if it didn't have any sarcastic remarks, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @MarinaDunst wow can't you take a joke? Is live so depressing?!

Comment: @Marina: I didn't read Rizier's comment as sarcastic - perhaps frustrated, maybe. Consider what it is like for helpful (high-rep) users when effort is expended on a post, only for the OP to try to delete it - it lacks the normal gratitude that oils the wheels of a community. Be positive here - you _are_ being helped. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Okay, let's say if you wouldn't have to use `$this`:

```
<?php

    function x(){echo "nope";}

    class A {           
        function x(){echo "x";}
        function y(){x();}          
    }

    $o = new A;
    $o->y();

?>
```

So this would call now the function `x()` in the class A. Means output is `x`, but if you now don't want to call the function `x()` from the class, but the other one, how do you want to say that? telekinesis?

How would you be able to call functions which aren't in the class, but have the same name as a class method? Do you want so that you can't use any functions from outside of the class definition?

So that's why you "say"(`$this`) that you now call a method from the class!

Comment: Perhaps I should've given an example myself. Im not questioning calling functions with instantiated objects. Are you sure your code is correct? It should be function y() {$this->x();} Your code will cause an error - call to undefined function. That's my point. Why use $this->x(); when logically it shouldve been just x().

Comment: @MarinaDunst *Are you sure your code is correct?* Yes: Are you sure your code is correct? But <- this lets me think that you don't really understand how classes and methods work. My code won't give you an error! Read my example again there I explain what it would do if it doesn't need `$this`

Comment: The answer IS clear and I'm upvoting. The code will NOT rise an undefined function exception, but will rather echo "nope" and not "x". This answer is clear, I don't get why it has been downvoted, and it clearly explains why you **need** to use $this. The thing you probably didn't get is that PHP, in such a case, looks for a **global** x() function if not strictly specified that it should be looking for its own one, because you may want to call a global function sometimes, else you wouldn't even be able to use PHP's own functions inside a class (like array_filter and so on)

Comment: Try using it without function x(){echo "nope";} - It explicitly needs $this even if there are no other functions with the same name. It's like its blind. So $this should've been used only if there are other functions with the same name, I mean logically.

Comment: "The thing you probably didn't get is that PHP, in such a case, looks for a global x() function" I get that. dont make assumptions.

Comment: @MarinaDunst ^ In theory it's correct, but it's not implemented like this in php! Also I think it's much easier if you have to use `$this` every time! Because then you say it every time that you use a class method now, because if you include multiple files into your project and you are programming, you would never know if there is a global function with the same name and you don't know which one it's calling. Also how do you want to call the global function if there is a method with the same name?!

Comment: @MarinaDunst And if you create a new global function maybe you will mess some other code up, because then it's calling the global function instead of the class method, so it would be very hard to find this error! So all in all it would be just a huge mess!

Comment: @Marina, I think a bare function reference, to be used if a global does not exist, would get confusing pretty quickly! I see what you mean, but I don't think a few keystrokes saved is worth the difficulty it would cause. PHP and its default extensions define a lot of functions in global space...

Comment: @halfer (@Marina) OP can also think like this: Does he wants to create a blacklist to block 200mio. IP's or create a whitelist and allow 2 IP's. (blacklist = without `$this`; whitelist = with `$this`)